# How to fix arguments and operators error, and can i outfile vector?

Tags: c++

i'm new to all this coding stuff.
So i'm trying to comparing some accounts names and these errors poped up: no instance of overloaded function getline matches the argument list, and no operator"<<" matches the operands.
Please explain, thanks a lot.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
    ifstream inFile("test.txt");
    if (!inFile)
 {
    cout << "Cannot open file.";
    exit(1);
 }
 string input;
 vector<string> tennguoikhac;
 vector<string> tennguoidung;
 cin >> input;
 tennguoidung.push_back(input);
 while (inFile)
 {
    inFile.getline(tennguoikhac);

    if (tennguoikhac == tennguoidung)
    {
        cout << "ten da co nguoi dung" << endl;
    }
}
ofstream outFile("test.txt");
if (!outFile)
{
    cout << "Cannot open file.";
    exit(1);
}
outFile << tennguoidung << endl;
outFile.close();
inFile.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://codebeautify.org/cpp-formatter-beautifier (please).

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`ifstream::getline`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) ?

Comment: Based on how they are used both `tennguoikhac` and `tennguoidung` should just be `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `getline` into vector. What you want is:

```
std::string tennguoikhacString;
std::getline(std::cin, tennguoikhacString);
std::istringstream tennguoikhacStream(tennguoikhacString);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter<>(tennguoikhac));
```

You also cannot directly print the vector:

```
outFile << tennguoidung << endl;
```

The closest you may want:

```
std::copy(tennguoidung.cbegin(), tennguoidung.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

Comment: True, but that doesn't answer the question. That's a different problem.

Comment: Still doesn't address the problem with `getline`.

Comment: Addressed that @Jabberwocky